# Installing Laravel with WAMP - Routers not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-routing

I installed Laravel with Composer, under wampserver.

My directory is: **C:/wamp/www/laravel/firstProject**

public file : **C:/wamp/www/laravel/firstProject/public**

SO when I try to go localhost/laravel/firstProject/public/projects

I get this error: **"The requested URL /laravel/index.php was not found on this server."**

I can access when I type: localhost/laravel/firstProject/public/index.php/projects

I edited httpd.conf and uncommented `mod_rewrite`.

Changed the `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride all`.

Also added `RewriteBase /laravel/` to .htaccess then restarted all but still having the same issue.

This is my routes.php file:

```
<?php

// show a static view for the home page (app/views/pages/home.blade.php)

Route::get('/', function() {
return View::make('pages.home');
});

Route::get('about', function() {
return View::make('pages.about');
});

Route::get('projects', function() {
return View::make('pages.projects');
});

Route::get('contact', function() {
return View::make('pages.contact');
});
```

This is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /laravel/
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I know the question was asked many times, yet I tried lots of the solutions provided, still the same..

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: I haven't used Laravel yet but I bet they have some examples or something like sandbox. Have you tried it? Also the most important thing here is. htaccess not your routing. And finally - have you restarted your Apache after changing configuration?

Comment: Yes I restarted but it's the same.

Comment: Post your .htaccess to gist or pastebin. I see there is one answer so try it before posting it.

Comment: edited and added the .htaccess, and trying that one now

Comment: that one solved! Thanks @jibe_84! There are lots of people having this problem, realized while I was searching a solution..

Comment: Ok, I see you have solved your problem so I don't have to download Laravel anymore. Good luck with further developing.

Comment: ah thanks a lot for trying to help @Northys :) to you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this .htaccess?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

it's the one from http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls

Answer (score 0):

I added following line in .htaccess file and its works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /learn/
```